# unlinked files and posix_fadvise(POSIX_FADV_NOREUSE)

Tags: linux

I'm curious: when I've read the contents of a file into memory and/or processed it and I'm going to unlink (delete) it, would it be useful to to a posix_fadvise(POSIX_FADV_NOREUSE) before closing the file? Or will the (Linux-)kernel automatically purge memory pages for files that no longer exist (inode)?
My idea for doing this posix_fadvise is to help the kernel freeing up memory that can be used for buffering of other activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIX_FADV_NOREUSE is currently ignored by the linux kernel. You might use POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED, but removed files are automatically purged from the cache anyway.

See [mm/fadvise.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/mm/fadvise.c#L115) and [fs/inode.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/inode.c#L717)